# LUKS add new password or key when only TPM unlock is available

Tags: fedora, encryption, luks, tpm

It seems like having no password is a big pain when working with any of the crypt tools like systemd-cryptenroll and cryptsetup!

I got a volume that is protected by pkcs11-uri=auto (Smart Card) and tpm2-device=auto (TPM chip)
they both work and I can map the volume at any time with /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup attach BUT, when I need to add a recovery-key for example, like

- cryptsetup luksAddKey
- systemd-cryptenroll --recovery-key

it will ask for a password or key file.

Since I got none of those I cannot do anything with the volume. To correct the situation I could just copy the data to another volume but the data is very large and in general that is not an OK situation for me

If you ask how I managed to do it, here is how :) systemd-cryptenroll --wipe-slot=password $device

It did not ask for a password!

I am on Fedora 35 Workstation, LUKS2, systemd v249

Comment: To see if an easy way exists. Are you using LUKS v1 (old, root can bypass it quite easily) or LUKS v2 (AFAIK, since Fedora 30, can't be exploited by root)?

Comment: I am on Fedora 35 Workstation, LUKS2 :( @A.B